# How to show uploaded image in dynamic rows?

Tags: magento2, dynamic-rows

I have added image field in dynamic rows like below

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    [
    'label' => __('Image'),
    'renderer' => $this->getImageRenderer()
]);

private function getImageRenderer()
{
    if (!$this->imageRenderer) {
        $this->imageRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blocks\Edit\Tab\ImageRenderer::class,
            '',
            ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
        );
    }
    return $this->imageRenderer;
}
```

ImageRenderer class

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Blocks\Edit\Tab;

class ImageRenderer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '<input type="file" name="' . $this->getInputName() . '" id="' . $this->getInputId() . '" ';
        $html .= '<image name="' . $this->getInputName() . '" id="' . $this->getInputId() . '" />';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Now I am able to browse image and save in database.

[image]

Now how to show uploaded image in the grid?

Most probable I would like to use _prepareArrayRow function like below to achieve it

```
protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        if (isset($row['image'])) {
            $image = $row->getImage(); // image path here
            // how to add image src from here
    }
```

My question is how to add html properties like img src in _prepareArrayRow function?

Comment: Did you managed to get it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Below function has worked for me to show image in admin form as well as grid:

```
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $storeViewId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $item = $this->_myCustomModelFactory->create()->setStoreViewId($storeViewId)->load($row->getId());
        $_images = $item->getImage();
        $src     = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $_images;

        return '<image style="max-width:100px;" src ="'.$src.'" alt="Preview" >';
    }
```

Comment: My class which is preparing column is extending `\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray` and render function is like `public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return parent::render($element);
    }` . Do you know how to customize this render function?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about that but this function is showing images on grid without any errors.